# SSIS error when transfering data from Oracle to SQL server

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

I am trying to run this SSIS package and I am consistently getting these error messages. I am not sure what to do...

> -1071636471   SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E51. An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80040E51  Description: "Provider cannot
>   derive parameter information and SetParameterInfo has not been
>   called.".
>
> -1073450901   "Get Date Ranges" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>
> -1073450996   One or more component failed validation.
>
> -1073594105   There were errors during task validation.

Comment: Find the data that caused `Get Date Ranges` to fail validation.

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to help without information on the package and specifically the component that is causing the error. What type of component is "Get Date Ranges"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The  source task was of the wrong type.